# Need a low latency but high fidelity solution to remotely monitor a robot

Tags: home-security, webcam

For work, there is a robot that I need to monitor and control remotely. I've tried some IP cameras, but they all had horrible latency. The cameras onboard my robot stream perfectly since they are using Theora compression, so at least my network is not any sort of bottleneck.

I'm looking for a good commercial off the shelf solution to having fixed and potentially pan/tilt cameras that can do some sort of video compression to minimize lag. My budget is less than $500 for a camera like this.

What are some good products that fit the bill? Or, what are some things to look for in a product?

Comment: How does latency compare to simple ping time? In other words, are you absolutely certain the camera is at fault?